# Laravel 5 how to include two custom helper files which needs to include one function in each other?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have having this issue where two of my custom helper needs to use one function from each other.

```
class CustomUserHelper {
    // Prepare variables
    protected $response;
    protected $CustomHelper;
    protected $CustomDatabaseHelper;

    // Prepare constructor
    public function __construct() {
        // Prepare variables
        $this->response = array();

        // Prepare classes
        $this->CustomHelper = app()->make('CustomHelper');
        $this->CustomDatabaseHelper = app()->make('CustomDatabaseHelper');
    }
}

class CustomDatabaseHelper {
    // Prepare variables
    protected $response;
    protected $CustomHelper;
    protected $CustomUserHelper;

    // Prepare constructor
    public function __construct() {
        // Prepare variables
        $this->response = array();

        // Prepare classes
        $this->CustomHelper = app()->make('CustomHelper');
        $this->CustomUserHelper = app()->make('CustomUserHelper');
    }
}
```

Doing this will cause a error 500 and I know that it might be due to the fact that the helper files are cross calling. Is there a way to resolve this?

Note: My helper files are called in the register() part from AppServiceProviders.

UPDATE 2017-04-19: I noticed that if I use aliases instead the issue is gone. Let me test it out.

Comment: This seems like a design problem. You've programmed in a circular dependency. Perhaps your classes do not have clear responsibilities and are trying to do the same thing?

Comment: @Scopey I admit that this might be due to the design issue from my helper files. I can easily solve this by placing the function in only one of the class but I would need to organize the helper files in a clean manner (database will handle database stuffs and so on).

Comment: even though its not a practice...Since they are helper functions you can define them statically. So you dont have to instantiate but you cannot override them afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In the end I have redesigned the functions again so that two helper class will not be calling each other. I have stored commonly used function in a general helper class for every other helper class to call.